# Распарсить svg файлы

Tags: php, svg

Есть несколько svg файлов следующего формата

```
<svg version="1.1" id="floor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1170 689" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1170 689;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path fill="#bbbbbb" id="1_1" stroke="none" opacity="1" d="M336,81 336,45 176,45 176,103 176,299 289,299 311,299 336,299 440,299 440,81Z"/>
    <path fill="#bbbbbb" id="1_2" stroke="none" opacity="1" d="M598,365 598,616 440,616 440,583 440,365Z"/>
    <path fill="#bbbbbb" id="1_3" stroke="none" opacity="1" d="M277,365 284,365 289,365 440,365 440,583 284,583 284,616 176,616 176,587 176,365Z"/>
    <path fill="#bbbbbb" id="1_4" stroke="none" opacity="1" d="M289,299 289,365 284,365 277,365 176,365 176,587 26,587 26,103 176,103 176,299Z"/>
    <path fill="#bbbbbb" id="1_5" stroke="none" opacity="1" d="M911,365 1016,365 1016,583 1131,583 1131,109 1016,109 1016,299 911,299Z"/>
    <path fill="#bbbbbb" id="1_6" stroke="none" opacity="1" d="M754,583 911,583 911,616 1016,616 1016,583 1016,365 911,365 754,365Z"/>
    <path fill="#bbbbbb" id="1_7" stroke="none" opacity="1" d="M858,81 754,81 754,299 858,299 893,299 911,299 1016,299 1016,109 1016,45 858,45Z"/>
    <path fill="#bbbbbb" id="1_8" stroke="none" opacity="1" d="M754,583 754,616 598,616 598,365 754,365Z"/>
</svg>
```

Можно ли как то распарсить пути на php. Необходимо заполнить массив где ключ в массиве будет `id`, а значение `d`?

Comment: любой библиотекой работающей с DOM моделью

Comment: Можно регуляркой: https://regex101.com/r/MTS1pr/7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$TEXT = <<<EXAMPLE
<svg version="1.1" id="floor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1170 689" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1170 689;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path fill="#bbbbbb" id="1_1" stroke="none" opacity="1" d="M336,81 336,45 176,45 176,103 176,299 289,299 311,299 336,299 440,299 440,81Z"/>
    <path fill="#bbbbbb" id="1_2" stroke="none" opacity="1" d="M598,365 598,616 440,616 440,583 440,365Z"/>
    <path fill="#bbbbbb" id="1_3" stroke="none" opacity="1" d="M277,365 284,365 289,365 440,365 440,583 284,583 284,616 176,616 176,587 176,365Z"/>
    <path fill="#bbbbbb" id="1_4" stroke="none" opacity="1" d="M289,299 289,365 284,365 277,365 176,365 176,587 26,587 26,103 176,103 176,299Z"/>
    <path fill="#bbbbbb" id="1_5" stroke="none" opacity="1" d="M911,365 1016,365 1016,583 1131,583 1131,109 1016,109 1016,299 911,299Z"/>
    <path fill="#bbbbbb" id="1_6" stroke="none" opacity="1" d="M754,583 911,583 911,616 1016,616 1016,583 1016,365 911,365 754,365Z"/>
    <path fill="#bbbbbb" id="1_7" stroke="none" opacity="1" d="M858,81 754,81 754,299 858,299 893,299 911,299 1016,299 1016,109 1016,45 858,45Z"/>
    <path fill="#bbbbbb" id="1_8" stroke="none" opacity="1" d="M754,583 754,616 598,616 598,365 754,365Z"/>
</svg>
EXAMPLE;


preg_match_all('/path(.*?) id="(.*?)" (.*?) d="(.*?)"/is', $TEXT, $OUT, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$RESULT = array();
foreach ($OUT as $key => $value) {
    $RESULT[$value[2]] = $value[4];
}
var_dump($RESULT);
```

Comment: Как вы ловко управляетесь с регулярками, завидую

Comment: @Алексей но сразу скажу, что она не идеальна, но конкретно под ТЕКУЩУЮ задачу подойдет :) P.S. с опытом придет